# Vulkan off-screen rendering: TILING OPTIMAL or LINEAR

Tags: vulkan

I'd like to build a off-screen renderer using Vulkan and copying the rendering content to host memory in each frame.

One scheme is using a frame image with TILING_OPTIMAL, and involving another copying render pass to copy the content to a host visible staging buffer.

The other scheme is using a frame image with TILING_LINEAR, and copying from the image directly.

I think the first scheme is more efficient, though involving one more copy step, but I'm not sure. And are there some more decent solutions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first solution is likely the better one.
`VK_IMAGE_TILING_LINEAR` is likely bad.
Non-`VK_MEMORY_PROPERTY_DEVICE_LOCAL_BIT` memory is likely also bad.
The first solution is double-buffered, which allows better overlap of device-local, and host-local work.

[Vulkan Device Memory](https://gpuopen.com/vulkan-device-memory/) article seems to recommend `HOST_VISIBLE` with `HOST_COHERENT` and `HOST_CACHED` as a staging buffer for things like screen-captures. Except as a spill memory, they do not even dare to mention GPU writes into non-`DEVICE_LOCAL` memory type.

[What’s your Vulkan Memory Type](https://developer.nvidia.com/what%E2%80%99s-your-vulkan-memory-type) mentions that memory types can be restricted based on image usage (`vkGetImageMemoryRequirements`). `VK_IMAGE_TILING_LINEAR` is guaranteed to have `HOST_VISIBLE` memory, but (as @Ekzuzy says) this restriction could manifest as `VK_IMAGE_TILING_LINEAR` `VkFormat` being unsupported for color attachment usage (preventing to do even `vkCreateImage`).

UMA devices might be worth measuring approach nr. 2. Those memory types would typically be `DEVICE_LOCAL|HOST_VISIBLE|HOST_CACHED`. Though still, copies can be fast, and rendering to badly tiled image can be too slow...

Comment: Thanks for shaing your wit. This is close to what I thought. Your answer gives me more confidence in the choice.

Answer (score 3):

You may find out that only the first solution is possible. Specification guarantees that only `VK_IMAGE_USAGE_TRANSFER_SRC_BIT` **and/or** `VK_IMAGE_USAGE_TRANSFER_DST_BIT` usages are supported for images with a LINEAR tiling. Other usages may also be supported but this support is not guaranteed. So the code You are going to implement may work on one platform, but may not work on other platforms and, depending on Your target, You may need to implement both solutions.

So first check if You are able to render directly into a linearly-tiled image. After that, if it is possible, perform Your own tests and check which solution is more optimal in Your case. Or - if You want to target more platforms - implement only the first, universal solution that should work everywhere.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your wit. The idea of your answer is similar to the other one. Tough you are the first to answer this question, the other provides some additional references which maybe useful for other readers. So I mark the other answer as the most recommended answer.

Comment: @魏晓萌 Totally agree ;-).